# How To Create a List in Chef-Inspec To Use Matcher be_in

Tags: ruby, inspec

I am trying to write a control that should check a list containing IPs and the config value that I am pulling from should be_in the list. I have no idea where to create this list that the control should reference.

```
control "Approved Management IPs" do
  impact 1.0
  title "Telnet Disabled"
  desc "Config should have one of the following IPs on the management plane."

  options = {
    assignment_regex: /^\s*(<permitted-ips>)(\w+)<\/permitted-ips>/,
    multiple_values: true
    }

  describe parse_config_file('pandevice_vm_config.txt', options) do
   its('<permitted-ips>') { should be_in LIST }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this syntax :

```rb
  describe parse_config_file('pandevice_vm_config.txt', options) do
   its('<permitted-ips>') { should be_in ['localhost', '192.168.0.1'] }
  end
```